# Copy a file using .mshs script

Tags: scripting, hyperion, essbase

I am trying to copy a file, export.txt from one directory to another within a .mshs script. I currently have:

```
shell copy 'E:\RPTG\Export.txt' 'E:\FCST\';
```

I'm getting an error that says "end of file breaks the statement."

Is there a command to copy a file with .mshs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would perform the copy from a batch file itself. For example, your batch file would do the copy, run a MaxL script, and then do other things. That said, you can run shell commands from within MaxL if you need to (I don't usually recommend it though). In this case, you need to pass the whole statement to the shell command. Your statement should work if you write it like this instead:

```
shell "copy 'E:\RPTG\Export.txt' 'E:\FCST\'";
```

Note that I have enclosed your command in double quotes. There are some nuances to using double quotes and single quotes at the same time, but in this case you should be okay.